# Do I need gold medals on all missions to get 100%?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I'm trying to get the [Career Criminal](http://www.trueachievements.com/a195100/career-criminal-achievement.htm) achievement for Grand Theft Auto 5 where you must get 100% game completion.

As part of this you must complete all story missions:

> Story Missions(69)- All Story Missions, including Lester's
>   Assassination Missions(available only to Franklin)

Do I need to get a Gold Medal in all missions, or is completing them enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need Gold Medals.

Here is a [100% completion checklist from IGN](http://www.ign.com/wikis/gta-5/100_Percent_Completion_Checklist).